# Wordpress Contact us 7 not code not working

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to hide the contact form after sending a message.
After a few research, I found out that I had to add extra code in the Additional Settings field.

I found a simple solution:

```
on_sent_ok: "document.getElementById('asaphide').style.display = 'none';"
```

but it was deprecated.

I then tried the following code that was on their website:

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    alert( "Fire!" );
}, false );
```

but it also didn't work.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the event listener to the document like so:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    alert( "Fire!" );
}, false );
```

Or like [in the docs](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/), create a `div` where you put this form:

> Be aware that the event target (wpcf7Elm in the example) is not a form
>   element, but its parent div element that has a wpcf7 class.

Comment: The first solution did not work, it didn't give an alert

Comment: @SaraKat I hope you didn't put this in the `Additional Settings field` but in a `<script>` tag or a separate JavaScript file.

Comment: it works now , thanks! I should've put it in a script file and not in Additional Settigns